# Custom UIPresentationController on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipresentationcontroller

I am customizing a `UIPresentationController` to simulate a presentation as iOS native `.OverCurrentContext` or `.CurrentContext`.

I find no matter what I override, the `presentingViewController` is always the `rootViewController` of UIWindow, does anybody know how to make it the `sourceViewController`(the one invoke `presentViewController:animated:completion`:) like the behavior of `.CurrentContext` presentation style?

And also a strange behavior, the `shouldPresentInFullscreen` method makes no difference if it returns true or false.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I’m observing exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `definesPresentationContext = YES` on your presenting view controller